# Why did Lt. Cole try to kill Kino?

Tags: kinos-journey

In the chapter "Land of Illnesses", Kino was tasked to send a gift to Logue, but is instead met by Lt. Cole and found out the truth about what happened to Logue and his family.

But why did Lt. Cole suddenly try to "kill" Kino?
If he wanted to use Kino as a test subject, it is in his best interest to capture her instead of trying to kill her.

What is he trying to achieve here?
Also, what happened after they both draw their gun?
Did Lt. Cole die?